# can't find pyside6-uic in a Linux-Manjaro

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I am using QT Creator for Python in Manjaro. I have installed python, pyside6, pyside6-tools ... But I do not know how to install or use pyside6-uic

Any idea how to solve this?

Find a way to use pyside6-uic in linux/manjaro

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Assuming you've the latest Qt version, just use the `uic` command with the related python output flag.

Comment: I have QT installed (as well as python, pyside6 ...). QT Creater asks me to use the command pyside6-uic to convert my.ui to .py. But I dont have pyside-uic and cant find that binary anywhere

Comment: I used uic -g python, but for some strange reason it uses pyside2, not pyside6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it turns out the uic binary in /usr/bin/ belongs to the Qt5 package, and it compiles on pyside2

I then saw that Qt Creator has its own uic binary, but it does not install it in /usr/bin/ or anything. I used that uic binary from Qt Creator and it works fine